# Error: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first; Problem: parent is null

Tags: android

I am trying to make a dynamic Gridlayout, 3 by 3 in portrait, or 5 by 5 in landscape. The plan is to fill the grid with ImageViews for a Tic Tac Toe game. During the game, players can choose to change the orientation so the grid will also change dimension. So i made the ImageViews fill the grid dynamically:

ImageView xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:onClick="choiceClick"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">

</ImageView>
```

the grid in main xml:

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvGame"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:id="@+id/grid">
    </GridLayout>
```

the code where i try to fill the grid:

```
GridLayout ttt = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    if (intent.getStringExtra("orientation").equalsIgnoreCase("p")){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        if (ttt.getChildCount() > 0){
            ttt.removeAllViews();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: " + iv.getParent()); // prints null
        if(iv.getParent() != null){
            ((ViewGroup)iv.getParent()).removeView(iv);
        }
        ttt.setRowCount(5);
        ttt.setColumnCount(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            iv.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
            ttt.addView(iv); //error here, The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        }
    }
```

I tried finding solutions but i already have the removeAllViews that i keep seeing. this current code does not use the image xml, i was previously trying the inflate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a FOR-LOOP and you try to add same "iv" multiple times to its "ttt" parent, so after one cycle "iv" already has a Parent....

Method rewritten (2nd time):

```
    final GridLayout ttt = findViewById(R.id.grid);
    final LayoutInflater cLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ttt.getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final String cOrientation = intent.getStringExtra("orientation");
    if (cOrientation.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
        ImageView iv;
        if (ttt.getChildCount() > 0) ttt.removeAllViews();
        ttt.setRowCount(5);
        ttt.setColumnCount(3);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            iv = (ImageView)cLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ImageView);
            //iv.setId(View.generateViewId());   //<-- I suggest to set ImageView ID here if you need it
            iv.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
            ttt.addView(iv);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ah okay yea that was the problem... but any suggestions to add all the imageviews into the grid? 9 isnt a lot but 25 is lol

Comment: I edited my answer with your method rewritten (I just fixed the logic but I don't know what you wanted to do in that GridLayout....)

Comment: thanks, my app is not crashing anymore, but is there a way that i can use the image view xml with this?

Comment: I added what you requested ;) Have a nice day.